# how to get next value of sequence from database and show it in JOptionPane in netbeans using oracle 10g?

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans

```
private void button_saveandsubmitnowActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        

           con = JavaConnectDB.ConnectDB();
    try{
       String sql="select MISSINGPERSON_SEQUENCE.nextval from DUAL";

       pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);     
       rs = (OracleResultSet) pst.executeQuery();

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nCase number: "+rs.getString(1));

      rs = (OracleResultSet) pst.executeQuery();


        if(rs.next()){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "the details have been added successfully!!!");
           con.close();
           this.dispose();
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "enter all fields appropriately first!!!");
        }
        con.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occured. try again later !!!");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, do you have a specific question about this code?

Comment: yes. the above code is executing i.e. the sequence value is incrementing but since i want to show that sequence no. in JOptionPane by taking that sequence value as string, it is not happening. as soon as i click on button an exception is occurring.

Comment: Maybe show us the exception message?  People here are not mind readers.